# TeamCity SSH-Exec Build step with password from parameter

Tags: ssh, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I have my build with SSH-Exec Build step (or SSH deployer), which requires username and password in its configuration to connect.

The problem I faced is that username can be provided by a parameter (so I can ask user when triggering build for his username) but I cannot do the same with password (it is masked and parameters reference is not supported in this field).

How can I configure a SSH-Exec Build step so password is taken from parameter?

(I'm aware of other then password auth methods, but I like explicitly ask the one who runs it for password to confirm he is in charge to run it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter a password parameter into the password field to use a parameter.  It still masks the value so it feels a little weird but it works.

Comment: Are you sure about it? I don't have an access to TC server any longer (left company) but that would be quite surprising :)

Comment: I have created quite a few SSHExec builds where I've entered the password parameter this way and it works.  By entering the parameter variable in the field TC knows that it needs to replace that with the value of the parameter.  It is misleading though where it's masked.